Showcase view scroll issue - Flutter Mobile App
showcaseview: ^3.0.0
final GlobalKey iconShowcaseKey = GlobalKey();

/////

VisibilityDetector(
       key: Key(
       'visibility_detector'),
       onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
       var visiblePercentage =
       visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;

       // Check if more than 50% of the widget is visible
       if (visiblePercentage > 50) {
        ShowCaseWidget.of(context).startShowCase([iconShowcaseKey]);
        print(" 50% visible");
         }
        },

      child: Showcase(
       key: iconShowcaseKey,
      descriptionPadding:
      EdgeInsets.all(2.sp),
      tooltipPosition: TooltipPosition.bottom,
      overlayOpacity: 0,
      tooltipBackgroundColor: ColorConstants.blackColor,
      descTextStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 10.sp,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      color: Colors.white,
      ),
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 12.sp,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      color: Color(0XFF3E3E3E),
      ),
      child:Container(
            height:100,
            width:80,
            color:Colors.red),
     description:"Click for options",
  )
 )
)

I am using a showcase view on my screen, but when scrolling within the Scaffold, the showcase tooltip occasionally misaligns with the target widget and appears in the wrong position. Do you have any suggestions for how to fix this?Thanks in Advance!!!

can you provide a screenshot of your result?

To resolve the issue and ensure the tooltip aligns correctly with the target widget, you can:
Delay the ShowCaseWidget.startShowCase Call.
Ensure the Widget is Fully Rendered Before Starting Showcase.
VisibilityDetector( key: Key('visibility_detector'),
onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;

// Check if more than 50% of the widget is visible
if (visiblePercentage > 50) {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    ShowCaseWidget.of(context)?.startShowCase([iconShowcaseKey]);
  });
  print("50% visible");
}
  },
child: Showcase(
key: iconShowcaseKey,
descriptionPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.sp),
tooltipPosition: TooltipPosition.bottom,
overlayOpacity: 0,
tooltipBackgroundColor: ColorConstants.blackColor,
descTextStyle: TextStyle(
  fontSize: 10.sp,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  color: Colors.white,
),
titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
  fontSize: 12.sp,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  color: Color(0XFF3E3E3E),
),
child: Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 80,
  color: Colors.red,
),
description: "Click for options",
),
)

